# How to Prevent Image SaveAs + Prevent Image Drag&Drop to Desktop + Prevent Screenshot on a Desktop Browser

Tags: php, javascript, html, image, screenshot

What are the best practices/methods/languages for Preventing the following:

- Image SaveAs
- Image Drag&Drop to Desktop
- Screenshots / Screengrabs

..on a desktop browser

(have witnessed the use of a 'blacked-out-screen' when a screenshot is attempted, and the implementation of images that are 'untouchable'..)

Comment: You can't reliably do any of those things.

Comment: Any progress towards these things is helpful.. Have seen the use of a 'blacked-out-screen' when a screenshot is taken, and the implementation of images that are untouchable..

Comment: i think you should write an OS or a custom browser !!!

Comment: If you've got something worth protecting, it's probably worth protecting from capable people as well as the ignorant. Browsers simply don't provide you with the tools necessary to do what you're asking in ways that aren't trivially circumvented.

Comment: @Mohammad How about a custom browser, built on existing technology, with the necessary tweaks? .. Any interested collaborators?

Comment: And whom would you convince to use such a browser, sourcingsynergy?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta .. Would be built in such a way that development-stage webpages/webapps could be built exclusively for viewing on this browser, such that developers/designers could use it to present work without any concern.. Any takers? Any interest?

Comment: Hmm. Well, if you have such a captive audience, it'd be worthwhile noting that in your question. Might shape the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the user right-clicking on the image and choosing Save As, you can add the code `oncontextmenu="return false"`. `oncontextmenu` detects the user right-clicking and `return false` stops the action.

Then if you do the code `draggable="false"` the user can't drag the image, even if they select it. I don't think there is a way to stop people using screengrabbers, but here is some code that stops Google Images and other search engines grabbing the image: `<meta name="robots" content="noimageindex"></meta>`.

So all in all, try this method: place `<meta name="robots" content="noimageindex"></meta>` in the head of your document, and then `<img src="mygreatimage.png" alt="An awesome image" oncontextmenu="return false" draggable="false">` in the document body.

Comment: One thing to note.. Both javascript functions work really well, though there is a way around the draggable="false".. If the image is highlighted, it can then be dragged occasionally.. Any tweaks?

Comment: You could disable the ability to select the image by using `style="-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-o-user-select:none;-user-select:none"`. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 5):

No Drag & Drop

```
document.getElementById('my-image').ondragstart = function() { return false; };
```

One way to prevent Save As (not really prevent but slow down a bit) would be to create a div with the inline styling that links to an image.

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background: url('yourcraphere.jpg');"></div>
```

I'm almost certain you cannot disable screenshots. Screenshots are not contingent on browser permission, that's an OS thing. You could try and white everything out if the user clicks the print screen button?

Users will always be able to look in your resources with a developer tool and grab whatever image you're using. Hopefully these methods will help prevent most people from stealing whatever content you may want to keep safe... you could also try a watermark. Hope that helps.